# Enable clicking on [Share] to automatically copy link to clipboard

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, hyperlinks, sharing

When the user clicks on the `[Share]` link under the post (either a question or an answer), a popup window appears with the link automatically highlighted. **I propose that the link should be automatically highlighted *and copied* to the clipboard.**

The most frequent action after clicking on `[Share]` is to copy and paste the link somewhere. I suggest to simplify the process. The link is *already* automatically highlighted. It is true that it is easy to copy: just use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or click on `[Copy link]`. We can save an extra step, and just copy it for the user.

[image: Share]

Comment: If we go this route, we'd have to make it optional. Otherwise people are going to be surprised by having their clipboard overwritten when they didn't intend to.

Comment: That would require a profile setting.

Comment: @Mast: Perhaps change the text `[Share]` to `[Copy link]`?

Comment: While that could work, if the company goes that route the Facebook and Twitter buttons become out of place.

Comment: @Mast: Maybe the text should be `[Copy link/Share]`? Then we can still have the Facebook and Twitter buttons in the window that opens.

Comment: I think that would unnecessarily take up space. Also, I wouldn't want to copy the URL text automatically if I just want to use the Twitter/Facebook buttons. There are many edge cases where your suggestion would not be preferable, so the UI is fine as it is.

Comment: Don't security concerns prevent access to the clipboard in web browsers?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Reading from the clipboard is a security concern, but a script can easily write to the clipboard, eg `javascript:(()=>{navigator.clipboard.writeText('Test')})()`

Comment: You can also just right-click the Share link and copy the link directly from there.

Answer (score 2):

No. That is a bad idea.

Personally, many times I browse Stack Exchange sites while at work, and in the middle of doing stuff, which might also include copy&paste of work-related things. I do not want to lose what I copied just because I clicked "share" link. That is simply bad.