# What's the benefit of keeping questions around that have negative votes? Isn't it just an embarrassment to the OP?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, down-votes, downvoted-questions

What's the benefit of keeping questions around that have negative votes? Isn't it just an embarrassment to the OP?

And the OP is discouraged to delete the question if the question has been answered by someone.

But isn't it an embarrassment to the OP? What can the OP do to avoid it given that the OP doesn't know how to improve his/her question?

Answer (score 16):

> What's the benefit of keeping questions around that have negative votes?

Depending on the circumstances, **they could be improved**. Some questions have seen dramatic turnarounds in the past.

Negative scores on questions [inform the "Roomba"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions), so it's not as if the questions are *always* kept around, anyway.

> And the OP is discouraged to delete the question if the question has been answered by someone.

Yes; the goal is to avoid any risk of losing information that could be helpful to someone else. Personally I think the system is far too conservative, but it is not at all arbitrary.

Deleting the question will not help the OP avoid a question ban. Improving it, such that others see fit to upvote (or retract their prior downvotes), will.

> But isn't it an embarrassment to the OP?

Downvotes are applied to content, not to users. But people who feel embarrassed might hopefully be motivated by that. That said, the evidence suggests that most people who ask bad questions are not really very interested in improving the question, understanding how Stack Exchange works, or really having any kind of positive interaction with the network as designed; they are interested in posting a request for help to a help desk or a discussion forum, and **we do not provide those things, full stop**.

> What can the OP do to avoid it given that the OP doesn't know how to improve his/her question.

Anyone who comes to a community is responsible for learning and understanding the basic rules, guidelines and social norms of that community - the community cannot be expected to change its policies to adapt to newcomers. Thus, an OP who does not know how to improve the question **should attempt to figure out how** to improve it, first. This could start, for example, with a post on Meta. (Per-site Metas generally require 5 reputation to post; but this requirement is waived for asking about one's own closed question, through an interface provided in the closure dialog.)

Comment: So, this question of mine got negative votes. And I don't know how to improve it because I don't have anything extra to write. Can you tell me how to improve it?

Comment: """"Downvotes are applied to content, not to users."""" - But the content was posted by the OP. So, downvotes to the content means that people didn't like OP's question and so OP will feel embarrassed.

Comment: I checked this page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) that you mentioned. Here, it looks like it says that there is a requirement for questions to get auto deleted - the requirement is that the question shouldn't have any answers. So, if a question has negative votes but someone has answered it, then the question will not be auto deleted.

Comment: "this question of mine got negative votes" - assuming you're referring to this very Meta question, downvotes work differently on Meta. Here, they can be used to express disagreement as well as to mark a question as unclear or unhelpful. In this case, I assume the downvotes are simply from people who disagree with the premise of the question, i.e. that downvotes are inherently embarrassing or that downvoted questions are not worth keeping.

Comment: Downvote means - "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." My question is not unclear. Also, I am writing from my own experience so there is research effort. So, the only thing that remains is that the question is not useful. May be it is not useful to some people so it got downvoted. But now, other people may also think that the question is not useful for them also. Who will waste their time in reading a question (and its answers/comments) that has negative votes? In general, I don't read questions (and their answers/comments) that have negative votes.

Comment: @Andrew: Don't take the voting system personally. The SE network is not a social media platform; we are a rule based analytical and objective Q&A platform. When using the site, let go of emotional narratives and engage with a focus on reason. Using the platform based on emotions will lead to discomfort.

Comment: @Andrew You were just told that meta voting includes agreement/disagreement. PS SO/SE has been around 15 years. The issues in this post are not new. Please research before considering posting a question. "my own experience" is the opposite of "research effort". Yet another duplicate (especially an uninformed one) is not a useful question. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. Meta sites generally have more discussion in comments, but if you want better answers edit your post appropriately.

Comment: @philipxy : What is research? Research means fact finding whether you find it out on Internet / books / or by own experience. The result of research is something that is backed up by proof. My own experience is also something that is backed up by proof. So, both things are same.

Comment: @philipxy : """"Yet another duplicate (especially an uninformed one)"""" 1. Can you please tell me that my question is duplicate of which question? 2. What is the meaning of uninformed here?

Comment: @philipxy : From your comment, it looks like you think that my post can be improved. I thought about it but I couldn't come up with any improvement. Can you please suggest how to improve my question?

Comment: @Andrew not research if it's true, research if it has been asked before. This question has been answered here before. Therefore an improvement would be not asking it again, since it already exists somewhere on the site. As an aside, your experiences are the exact opposite of "backed by proof": they are nothing but subjective. And this question proves it.

Comment: see [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) where the restriction against deleting your own question was first put in place, and why

Comment: @Esther : I saw the meta question. But it is about deleting any type of question and my question is about deleting questions having negative votes. So, both are different.

Comment: @Esther : Can you please tell me that my question is duplicate of which question? Please post the link.

Comment: @Esther : From my experience I came to know that the OP is discouraged to delete the question if the question has been answered by someone. And, you are saying that this is subjective and not a proof. Please think again.

Answer (score 8):

> What's the benefit of keeping questions around that have negative votes? Isn't it just an embarrassment to the OP?

As someone who has received thousands of downvotes on my questions, I don't care about votes: I only care about learning. Deleting or closing good questions prevents me from learning.

Comment: Wouldn't the downvotes suggest the question was unpopular or low in quality? Don't get me wrong, I've had my share of heavily downvoted posts too, the community at MSE are a hard-to-please-bunch if you go against the community grain.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні  I've had plenty of good questions that received downvotes. I think we have to keep in mind that about half of the votes are cast by people with an IQ below 100.

Answer (score 5):

> What's the benefit of keeping questions around that have negative votes?

**There are many questions with multiple negative votes that nevertheless have excellent answers.** Often these answers are highly upvoted, and the (downvoted) question can accumulate a large number of views. All of this suggests that many people have found some combinations of (downvoted) questions and the (good) answers useful on the whole.

> Isn't it just an embarrassment to the OP?

**I do not take downvotes personally. I find them very useful.** I learn a lot from them, especially when they are followed up by comments and/or answers. The downvotes are not any more embarrassing than getting comments and suggestions during code review. They are meant as a feedback mechanism, not to embarrass anyone. Moreover, on Meta sites downvoting means not necessarily that the question is *bad*, but rather that others **disagree with your proposal**. That knowledge is useful in itself.

Some downvoted questions must be kept around for the reasons I outlined.

Of course, there are tons and tons of poor quality questions. They must be deleted, and there are both manual and automated ways by which they get deleted and their electrons get recycled for more productive use.

**Examples:**

**Downvoted questions with useful answers:**

- [Safer `eval` in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66567722/safer-eval-in-python)
- [Fix ansible-playbook error: "ERROR! the role 'zzet.rbenv' was not found in ..." - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025783/fix-ansible-playbook-error-error-the-role-zzet-rbenv-was-not-found-in)

**Downvoted Meta question because users disagree with the proposal:**

- [Display user reputation on mouseover for the list of the users who closed the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360563/578690)
- [Enable clicking on [Share] to automatically copy link to clipboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379606/578690)